# Bubble up the parent document using .on("load")

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble with run the script only after entire page has loaded.
My code below bubble up the parent document and the function gets executed before complete loading of DOM elements. To solve the problem and get the code running correct, I’m using setTimeout().

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/ads/cn/cn.php'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).on("load", function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
          alert( $( '.cell_link span' ).text() );
    }, 2000);
});
</script>
```

Not using the timer, the result is empty `alert` message (without the data).

Is there other solution than using the timer?

Comment: How do you load `$( '.cell_link span' )` into DOM???

Comment: The element should be available on document.ready, unless it's loaded dynamically with ajax, then you'd have to hook into the ajax function.

Comment: I load through cn.php (see my code)

Comment: Then why not use onload callback of cn.php script tag? Anyway, window onload should be fired after, so obviously you didn't bring to us all relevant information here in question. BTW, i have no idea what are you talking about `My code below bubble up the parent document` ??? What bubbles?!

Comment: This code trigger the script through cn.php <div class='adfreely' rel='FA001'></div>

Comment: I'm not sure to understand any of your comments above. So, how do you add `'.cell_link span'` element into the DOM??? Or maybe, how do you set this element content? (the thing you expect the text() method to return)

Comment: This script written in PHP with MySQL backend, I set the elements for  cell_link content directly on MySQL.